# Windows keep spontaneously moving from workspace to workspace in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I keep finding windows have moved from one workspace to another. This is often correlated with my opening something in fullscreen mode, but not always.

Does anybody know how to make my windows stay in the workspace where I put them?

Also, to expand; I want windows to stay where I put them without having to go to the dock icons and explicitly assigning workspaces.

Also, I'd like to do this on a per-window basis, not per-app. For example, I often keep browser windows open in workspace #2 for documentation, and other browser windows in workspace #1 for general browsing. I also like to keep some Terminal windows in workspace #2 for editing documentation, and windows in workspace #3 for editing source code.

It drives me nuts to occasionally find all my windows scattered to different workspaces, and now I have to manually put them back where I wanted them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open System Preferences => Mission Control and uncheck "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use".

In addition to that, I don't think they will always go back to the same window unless you assign them there. If you do assign them, they will stay.

Problem solved.

Comment: Damn, I had no idea that option existed or that it had somehow become checked. Thank you. It will be a few days of testing before I know for sure, but I'm pretty sure this is the answer. I wish I knew the algorithm that Mac uses to decide how and when to rearrange things.

Comment: Thanks! This is the stupidest default I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, make sure you are on the desktop you want the window on, try right clicking on the dock icon for the program you wish to keep in a certain desktop, mouse to "options" then click "This Desktop". That should keep it on the desktop you want it on. Also something I use occasionally, there is an option to make it stay on all desktops, if there is something you want present even after switching desktops.

If this is not exactly what you need, elaborate on your description, we'll see what we can come up with.

Comment: I think your answer would require me to do this one-by-one for each app. Plus, I suspect that's a "per-app" and not "per-window", which is what I want. I'll update my description.

Comment: p.s. thanks for pointing this feature out. The option to place an app on all windows can come in handy.

Comment: Yes it is usually per app, you are correct. Are there any multiple monitors in play here? Or is this a single monitor? How many work spaces (desktops) are in play as well?

Comment: If it were happening to me I might try deleting plist files for all affected apps, or even creating a new profile, logging in AS that profile and then using the computer for a day or three to see if the same behavior occurs. If not, move my stuff to the new profile, delete the old one and call it fixed.

Comment: This is a single-monitor configuration on a laptop. I'll give some of your suggestions a try.